# Facebook Actionscript API 'Facebook.Init()' call is suddenly returning null session object. Why?

Tags: facebook, flash, facebook-graph-api, facebook-actionscript-api

I have a game on Facebook that has been running successfully for almost a year now. It went offline this morning because my Flash Client which calls the facebook-actionscript-api:

Facebook.init(app_id, handleLogin)

...function, started getting a null response. And no error. The handleLogin() callback is called, function handleLogin(response:Object, fail:Object):void ...but both response and fail objects are null.

It started a little before 7pm, (19:00) Tuesday 8/May/2012 (PDT) - (California Time)

Anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: Having the same problem with our flash game since about midnight (GMT+2). Trying to figure out the problem and a solution right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes we are also seeing the same issue as of midnight last night. We are still not sure the root cause of the problem. Trying to engage with facebook to find out.

Anyone else getting this?

update: Looks like a similar thing being reported in facebook bugs

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/440387422643581?browse=search_4faa2351ce3059948026603

Comment: Check the comment by Craig Robinson: "Same issue. It looks like FB.JSON (in all.js) changed. It is being used by the as3 SDK. A workaround for modern browsers is to replace "FB.JSON" with "JSON" in script_js in the file FacebookJSBridge.as in the as3 SDK."

Comment: Except it doesn't work for IE8. But Craig did mention 'modern browsers'

Comment: Works for most browsers, but we're still seeing issues for IE7.
Initially, I thought that the fix would only work for modern browsers too (it seems to rely on a native JSON parser, which for example, Chrome has but IE doesn't) but Facebook inserts a JSON parser shim into the page. 
Facebook mention this here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295956663824256 and you can see it working in IE9. However the JSON object doesn't seem to be there in IE7. Also seeing this on other sites such as takethislollipop.com. Can anyone else confirm that they are seeing this issue?

Comment: FYI, We added a JSON shim and now we're good : https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 0):

I know facebook just dropped offline access from permissions... maybe check you aren't requesting it in your login scope.  I had a problem with it messing up my facebook login process, but on monday.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the temporary fixed API from here and replace the GrapApiWeb_1.8.1.swc

http://www.superurchin.com/FacebookGraphApi_Superurchin.swc.zip

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has fixed the bug , so we don't have to worry about it now. :)

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/295956663824256

Comment: Please read the full report - Facebook has simply temporarily re-added som deprecated methods that third-parties should not be relying on. These will be removed again at a later time.

Comment: I agree, and that's why I use the word "now". 
just wait for the new version of AS3 SDK for Facebook.