# Uncaught Error: No polyfill registered for object Facebook JDK

Tags: java, facebook-login

I am getting the following error using the Facebook JDK for Login, pretty sure this has only just started happening within the last 1 or 2 days, is anybody experiencing this aswell? Here is my JS code and then Error

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //Fire Login Ajax
    } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                    //Fire Login Ajax
                });
            }
        });
    }
});

Uncaught Error: No polyfill registered for object
q    all.js:24
FB.subclass.process    all.js:118
FB.provide._processElement.processor    all.js:82
FB.provide._processElement    all.js:82
FB.provide.parse    all.js:82
q    all.js:24
FB.provide.parse
```

Comment: A site I work on started getting the same error last night. I'm trying to debug it at the moment...

Comment: So looking at where the exception occurs, they populate an array with some typenames and later on try to dereference an element in the array using `.toLowerCase()`. This makes the key value `'object'` rather than `'Object'` so the element is not found and the exception is thrown.

Comment: ...either they need to consistently call `toLowerCase()` when populating the array (some of the other keys are in lower case), or remove the `toLowerCase()` when accessing, not sure which. Either way, doesn't seem like a difficult fix, hopefully it gets sorted out soon. :)

Comment: Looks like a bug ticket has already been created for this :)
[link]http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/420667497951980

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug. It's reported at https://developers.intern.facebook.com/bugs/420667497951980, it's under investigation.

Please have a look at [Facebook Actionscript API 'Facebook.Init()' call is suddenly returning null session object. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510907/facebook-actionscript-api-facebook-init-call-is-suddenly-returning-null-sess)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to a site I have last night. I traced the problem to this line:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

If I comment this line, no error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It's a FB API problem.

JS SDK issues
today at 7:42am
Currently, the all.js file is throwing an exception on load. We are working on a fix now. For more information and updates, please subscribe to bug 420667497951980.

Always keep a eye to the FB developer page

Answer (score 0):

This works if FQL fails

```
FB.api({
    method: 'fql.query',
     query: 'SELECT name, uid, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid=me()'
    },
   function(rows) {
      // Process here
    }
 )
```